# How to load current date to DB2 through a Perl script?

Tags: perl, db2

I am trying to fetch records from `NAMES` table in DB2 through `Cursor C1` and load it to another table with `Current Date` using a Perl script:

```
db2 "DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR SELECT F.ID, F.NM from NAMES ;
db2 "load from C1 OF CURSOR method N(ID, CURRENT DATE) insert into STAGE(ID, INS_DT) nonrecoverable" > $LoadC1Results
```

I have tried using

```
my $date = localtime->strftime('%Y-%m-%d');
```

(or)

```
DateTime->now->strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

But still not able to load. Getting errors like `SQL1191N , '14-12-05' not correct`.

Comment: Why are you selecting `F.NM` if you never use it? The fields in `method N(...)` must reference column names present in the cursor, and `CURRENT DATE`, on top of being an invalid identifier, is not present in the cursor.

Comment: If you have phpadmin, try changing the type of the field (where you are trying to put the time) to "Date&Time" or something similar. A regular field is not as efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
db2 "declare c1 cursor for select id, current date from names"
db2 "load from c1 of cursor insert into stage(id, ins_dt)"
```